# Select data from Sybase database but only select the row with the highest sequence

Tags: sql, database, sybase

I'm trying to select data from my database from the highest sequence number, I have been struggling with this for a while and cant get it to work.

The database has a lot of Columns with data. I only want data from the row with the highest sequence number to search in, because the data from lower sequences is not of any value for me. Unfortunately the rows from the lower sequences can not be deleted.

Database looks like this:

```
-----------------------------
| ID | SEQ | rest of the data
-----------------------------
| 1  |  1  | ..
| 1  |  2  | ....
| 2  |  1  | ..
| 1  |  3  | ....
| 3  |  1  | ..
| 1  |  2  | ....
| 4  |  1  | ........
```

My question is, how can i select only the ID's with the highest sequence number and search in those rows with the `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 2):

On oracle11g you can use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (       
      SELECT YOUR_TABLE.*, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID oRDER BY SEQ DESC) RN 
      FROM YOUR_TABLE) A 
WHERE RN=1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I checked the database to be sure. I'm using a  Sybase SQL. Your query didn't work unfortunately

Comment: @Wvs You should have checked that before adding oracle and other databases in your tags. Now this person did lookup and other work for you for nothing

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SEQ DESC ) AS rn
  FROM   your_table t
)
WHERE  rn = 1
```

or

```
SELECT ID,
       MAX( seq ) AS seq,
       MAX( other_column_1 ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY seq ) AS other_column_1,
       MAX( other_column_2 ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY seq ) AS other_column_2
      -- ...
FROM   your_table
GROUP BY id
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table t
WHERE  seq IN ( SELECT MAX( seq )
                FROM   your_table x
                WHERE  x.id = t.id )
```

or

```
SELECT t.*
FROM   your_table t
       INNER JOIN ( SELECT id, MAX( seq ) AS seq
                    FROM   your_table
                    GROUP BY id ) x
       ON ( x.id = t.id AND x.seq = t.seq )
```